# Android Device fonts override

Tags: android

I have an application that uses webviews extensively. My webviews have a set font but if I change the default fonts of my android device, they seem to be overridden.
Is there a way I can override my application from native fonts to the webview fonts?

Comment: Show us the code where you're trying to change the fonts.